# Django from_email defaulting to recipient

Tags: python, django

Im using Django, anymail API & mailgun to send emails from my site.

I have a form where users can subscribe,
At present when the email is send to the subscriber's email address, the FROM address default to a combination of their and my email domain.

**As an exmample:**

User enters  test@test.com an receives email from test=test.com@mail.mydomain.com and not the one I specified of info@mydomain.com

I am pretty sure the problem is within my views.py, but im not sure how to resolve.

views.py

```
def send_email(subject, html_content, text_content=None, from_email=None, recipients=[], attachments=[], bcc=[], cc=[]):
    # send email to user with attachment
    if not from_email:
        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    if not text_content:
        text_content = ''
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject, text_content, from_email, recipients, bcc=bcc, cc=cc
    )
    email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    for attachment in attachments:
        # Example: email.attach('design.png', img_data, 'image/png')
        email.attach(*attachment)
    email.send()


def send_mass_mail(data_list):
    for data in data_list:
        template = data.pop('template')
        context = data.pop('context')
        html_content = get_rendered_html(template, context)
        data.update({'html_content': html_content})
        send_email(**data)


# Contact Form - home.html
def HomePage(request, template='home.html'):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        # Create message1 to send to poster
        message1 = {
        'subject': 'Test',
        'from_email': from_email,
        'recipients': [from_email],
        'template': "marketing/welcome.html",
        'context': {
                    "from_email": from_email,

                    }


        }
        # Create message1 to send to website admin
        message2 = {
        'subject': 'Test - Contact',
        'from_email': from_email,
        'recipients': ['info@mydomain.com'],
        'template': "marketing/admin.html",
        'context': {             
                    "from_email": from_email,
                    }


        }

        try:
            send_mass_mail([message1, message2])

        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('/thanks/')
    context = {
            "form": form,

        }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are using the `from_email` from the user, not `info@mydomain.com`. In two places you have:

```
'from_email': from_email,
```

Many mail providers will limit the addresses that you can send mail from (to stop you sending spam using someone else's address.

Therefore you can't use a `from_email` that the user gives you. The usual approach is to use your own address as the `from_email`, but set a reply-to header so that any replies go to the address that the user specified.